# htaccess prevent hotlink also prevents external links

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've got this code in my .htaccess file to prevent hotlink of images and pdf files but it is also preventing normal external links to work. 
My htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mywebsite.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg|pdf|png)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/images/notallowed.jpe [NC,R,L]
```

Problem is that a legitime external link to say a pdf file will cause the replacement image to appear instead of the pdf file.
¿Is this normal or what am I doing wrong/missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'd give this a try...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(?:www\.)?mywebsite\.com(?:$|/) [NC] [OR]
# Repeat the next line as needed for each allowed site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(?:www\.)?allowedsite1\.com(?:$|/) [NC] [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(?:www\.)?allowedsite2\.com(?:$|/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|jpg|pdf|png) http://www.mywebsite.com/images/notallowed.jpe [NC,R,L]
```

Might be kind of inconvenient to manually add each allowed site, but it *should* give you some control... Other possible drawback would be that the people visiting a raw image, for example, would have to do so via an existing link found within the site.

Example: typing `http://www.mywebsite.com/logo.png` into your browser and trying to *directly* view the file `logo.png` wouldn't work, **but** you shouldn't have a problem viewing the same file if you click on `<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/logo.png"><img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/logo.png" /></a>`.

Hope that helps someone...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried but nope! Doesn't work either. I don´t really understand why.

Comment: Yeah actually I meant to edit that answer (which maybe I'll do right now, just for everyone else who might be in a similar situation), because I realized that will block everyone who's not listed as "allowed" (e.g. the entry on the second line).

Comment: No way. It doesn`t work. Let me explain. If I put a pdf file of mywebsite in an iframe (outside my web site) the pdf is replaced by the image which is what I want. But if in the same program I put a link like <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/pdf/mypdffile.pdf" target="_blank"> the pdf still is not showing, it gets replaced by the image which is not what I need. So I don't see this as a problem of adding more allowed sites but to change something else in the code instead. Thanks again anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SetEnvIf](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html) instead:

```
SetEnvIf Referer ^http remote

<FilesMatch "\.(png|gif|jpg|pdf)">
  order deny,allow
  deny from env=remote
  allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```